# Why xcalib invert screen doesn't work with ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I use the inverted colors mode a lot, however after installing ubuntu 12.10 it doesn't work for me any more. The command:

```
xcalib -i -a
```

Outputs:

```
Error - unsupported ramp size 0
```

I have no clue where to start looking to fix this problem. Couldn't find anything about this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gamma ramp is not defined (0), but `xcalib` expects multiples of 16. Installing `gcm` solved the issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-color-manager
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Please explain this method, how have you figured out to install `gcm`? Maybe I find a similar solution for me. I'm using xfce. Inverting works on 3 different monitors, including the notebook's, but doesn't work on a fourth monitor (Samsung S23B350).

Comment: Doesn't work for me either on Cinnamon. Used to work until a few weeks ago. Using Debian Stretch, not sure what got updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea (I had the same problem with Xubuntu 17.10.1, and this solution worked for me): Use the solution provided in Anwar's answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930084/xcalib-error-unsupported-ramp-size).

Create the following filepath (I had to make the directory called xorg.conf.d, too): `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and add these lines to the file (then save and restart your computer afterward):

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"
EndSection
```