# Easiest way to invert colors on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display

What's the easiest way to invert colors on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver on the display output?

Comment: One way is to install [xcalib](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xcalib.1.html) and to use `xcalib -i`. If you have Intel graphics and encounter the "unsupported ramp ..." error, [Anwar's fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930084/xcalib-error-unsupported-ramp-size) may help.

Comment: [Tom Brossman](https://askubuntu.com/users/12864/tom-brossman) says   and I agree "
It's not explicitly clear from OP's question, but I am pretty sure they are asking how to invert colors for the display output, and not an individual JPEG file like in your answer. "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As DK Bose notes, you could use `xcalib -invert -alter`, but this will only affect your main monitor if you use more than one. Instead, you could try [this program](https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors) from Zoltan Padrah, which was appears to have been created specifically as a workaround for this problem.

```
git clone https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors.git
cd xrandr-invert-colors
 # install dependency libxcb-randr0-dev :
sudo make deps-apt
make
sudo make install
```

... and run with `/usr/local/bin/xrandr-invert-colors`.

Note that the `sudo make install` step is optional; you could just run the `xrandr-invert-colors.bin` executable directly from the source dir.

Set a keyboard shortcut for this however you like (say, with Settings > Keyboard).

Since this works by adjusting the color output, it can be undone by, e.g., Ubuntu 18's built-in redshift/f.lux analog, which periodically readjusts your colors, so be sure that "Night Light" is disabled in Settings > Display.

**Edit:** In Ubuntu 19.04 and maybe 20 too, there's a Gnome Shell extension "InvertDE" which is a thin wrapper around xcalib that might be of use. Since I have my own xcalib script at this point, I'm not using it. Additionally, there's the extension "Invert Window Color" that applies to individual windows.

**Edit five months later:** I've reinstalled to 20.04, and found that @Xaser is indeed right, and xcalib by itself works for me. It might also be that I now have two equal-shape monitors. I'll be using that, or the "InvertDE" extension method for now, as the least custom. But will certainly leave the other stuff here.

Comment: for me xcalib affects both monitors.