# xcalib error - unsupported ramp size

Tags: display, colors, contrast, xcalib

I'm trying to change the contrast with `xcalib` with the command `xcalib -co 70` but I get the following error:

```
Error - unsupported ramp size 0
```

Comment: According to the [xcalib README](http://xcalib.sourceforge.net/README.html) the last parameter must be an ICC profile, or `-a` or `-alter` as described in this previous Q&A [How to adjust contrast with xcalib](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230592/how-to-adjust-contrast-with-xcalib)

Comment: I tried, same error.

Comment: @TomásAntunes Have you tried the mentioned solution?

Answer (score 11):

This is actually a bug as reported [upstream in debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851810) and various other places. It seems newer version of X caused this. A user reported a workaround for intel drivers and it worked for me.

First of all, do make sure that the [appropriate drivers are actually installed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851810#25): `$ sudo apt install xorg xserver-xorg-video-intel`

You need to create a xorg `.conf` file to force usage of intel drivers. Create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and put these lines there.

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

**On Ubuntu 18.04 and newer,** the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` should contain `Driver "intel"` under the `Section "Device"`. The `Identifier` may be called differently.

Now **reboot** or **restart X** (`sudo systemctl restart display-manager`).

Comment: how can I avoid the reboot?

Comment: You can try restarting X

Comment: Thank you. Solved my problem but somehow I didn't find the xorg.conf.d folder inside /etc/X11, I am using Ubuntu 18.04 so I made the directory, placed the file inside that and added the same code to a new file in /etc/X11/Xsession.d/20-intel.conf

Comment: This doesn't work in Dell XPS13 Developer Edition: I cannot login after doing this

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo what is your system? I have ubuntu 18.04 and thinkpad t460s with intel skylake, does not work for me after creating the file

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 in a stock Lenovo T400 Thinkpad. The solution worked pretty fine but somehow dual boot with Windows wiped out the boot loader so I have only Windows on that machine. Will fix later. My kid use the laptop for university homework. Impossible to gain access now.

Answer (score 4):

**On Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier**

The [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/945565/726502) has worked for me quite well.

**On Ubuntu 18.04**

I came across [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2383643.html) stating that the `xcalib` in the Ubuntu repository is too old - built in 2008. There have been updates to the [xcalib repository](https://github.com/OpenICC/xcalib). So, you can clone the git repository from there, and build and install.

Firstly, you need to have git, make and cmake:

```
sudo apt install git cmake make
```

You will also require the following libraries:

```
sudo apt install libx11-dev libxrandr-dev libxxf86vm-dev
```

And the main steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/OpenICC/xcalib.git
cd xcalib
cmake CMakeLists.txt
sudo make install
```

You can uninstall by running:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

One (those new to Linux) can search for these by

```
apt-cache search [some-keyword]
```

Besides,

**My Experience**

For me (on XPS 9570) (and at least one more), the [other solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/945565/726502) didn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 - it simply didn't work, besides the fact that it disables brightness keys. I have relied on that solution for inverting screen colours for quite some time - it did work on (X)Ubuntu 16.04, Debian Stretch.

Now, thanks to google - I have been googling since more 3 days - to me, it seems google keeps searching for your query when you're offline, so that it can give you more relevant results when you search for it again.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to use xcalib, failed to so it, and your answer was the solution for me!

Answer (score 1):

As described by @Serge Stroobandt I created the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file and put these lines there

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Intel Graphics"
  Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

This eliminated the 'unsupported ramp size' error but created a new [missing letters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters) issue. I then proceeded to modify `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` to contain the following body. This fixed the [missing letters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters) issue. But now I take a big performance hit. I wish there was a better solution. I tried @WorkWise `Tweak Tool > Fonts > Antialiasing change from  Subpixels Antialiasing to Standard Grayscale Aliasing` but it didn't fix the [missing letters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters) issue.

For now just put this body in your `20-intel.conf` file and that's as good as it's going to get.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

> **Option "AccelMethod"** "*string*"
>
> Select acceleration method. There are a couple of backends available for accelerating the DDX. "UXA" (Unified Acceleration Architecture) is the mature backend that was introduced to support the GEM driver model. It is in the process of being superseded by "SNA" (Sandybridge's New Acceleration). Until that process is complete, the ability to choose which backend to use remains for backwards compatibility. In addition, there are a pair of sub-options to limit the acceleration for debugging use. Specify "off" or "none" to disable all acceleration, or "blt" to disable render acceleration and only use the BLT engine.
>
> Default: use SNA (render acceleration)

[*Source*](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/intel.4)

Comment: As demonstrated in [SNA Acceleration vs. UXA Acceleration](http://cynic.cc/blog/posts/sna_acceleration_vs_uxa/), the default and newer SNA acceleration method is twice as fast if it works.