# How to adjust my display contrast and colors

Tags: display, colors

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and I want to adjust the color gamma, and contrast of the display. I am using notebook, video card is AMD Radeon R5 M255, Ubutnu 17.10.

The purpose of this is to make the display nice to my eyes, it's not calibrating for photo purpose or anything like that. Since I switched to Ubuntu things seem blurred to me, so I am looking for a way to improve that.

I tried

```
   xgamma -gamma 0.8
```

the output is

```
-> Red  0.000, Green  0.000, Blue  0.000
<- Red  0.000, Green  0.000, Blue  0.000
```

And nothing changes.

I wasn't able to find anything useful in settings. I downloaded some color profiles and tried them in  Settings -> Devices -> Color. But there is no significant difference. I think I need something I can experiment with adjusting +/- the properties instead of predefined profiles.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the redshift tool, it has an auto option as well as a manual mode.

```
sudo apt-get install -y redhsift redshift-gtk
```

for a nice warm red which was nice on my eyes especially at night

```
redshift -x 5000
```

read the man page for more tuning ideas

Comment: Unfortunately this is not changing my screen in any way. even with values like `redshift -O 3000 -v -g 0.300:0.300:0.300 -b 0.3:0.2` display is not changed.  It reports 'Brightness: 0.30:0.20
Gamma (Daytime): 0.300, 0.300, 0.300
Gamma (Night): 0.300, 0.300, 0.300
Using method `randr'.
Color temperature: 3000K' but no visual change

Comment: this was my mistake, I think ubuntu 17.10 defaults to wayland and I don't know if redshift works here or not... Maybe try xcalib?

Comment: xcalib is not working either, as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/930084/xcalib-error-unsupported-ramp-size. The workaround described there is not working for me either. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.