# I tried all the answers I saw on the internet, but xcalib still doesn't work on my Ubuntu 22.04.2. What to do?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 22.04, display, xcalib

I am an Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS user. I enjoy using linux distributions, but I still consider myself a novice in using terminal commands.
My laptop is an ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. Processor: Z450LA. Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4. Graphics: desktop Intel® HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2).

Previously used this same machine with Ubuntu 20.04.6. I upgraded to the new version of Ubuntu recently.

I have always used xcalib to invert the colors of my screen.

So now that I have upgraded my computer system I went to install xcalib using:
``sudo apt-get install xcalib```
Everything runs fine.

But the command I always use, `xcalib -invert -alter`, or ``` xcalib -i -a`` didn't work, and the following output came up: ``` Error - unsupported ramp size 0```

I tried following what was in this answer: [xcalib error - unsupported ramp size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930084/xcalib-error-unsupported-ramp-size)

First I tried these steps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1087465/1705480
There was no solution with that. Actually if I try:
`xcalib -i -a` , nothing happened.

Then I tried these steps:
https://askubuntu.com/a/945565/1705480
And still nothing happened.
***The screen is still the same colors.***

Truthfully, the only change is that I now have xcalib 0.10.0 installed and cloned from GitHub, and if I type any incomplete commands, like `xcalib -i`, I get the output: `Warning - Unable to read file ''`

What can I do to run xcalib correctly on my notebook and invert the colors on my screen?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: https://github.com/OpenICC/xcalib 0.10 was last modified 9-10 years ago, I would not expect it to work - especially with 22.04 (which introduced a new way of driving the display).

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I think disabling Wayland make it work, if xcalib was working on 20.04 without problems.

Comment: @Hannu, according to `git log`, last commit was on 2023-01-12, and the related to code changes commit is dated on 2019-01-12. Moreover, `xcalib` works flawlessly on most of my setups, including Ubuntu 22.04. The probable reason has been stated above: Wayland doesn't support a lot features of Xorg/X11, therefore switching to Xorg might resolve the isssue.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue yet? If no, it would be nice to know your video driver setup! What `inxi -Gx` tells you?