# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS: my /home folder "broke"

Tags: gnome, home-directory

I was trying to use xcalib, and ran into an error (see [xcalib error - unsupported ramp size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930084/xcalib-error-unsupported-ramp-size/1483654#1483654)) and followed Anwar's method, rebooted my computer and then this happened.

[Gnome see of /home folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRGK6.png)

[My Desktop area is with some /home files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD6C2.jpg)

When i try to enter "Downloads", it gives error:

```
$ cd Downloads
bash: cd: Downloads: To many levels of symbolic links
```

It has something to do with symlinks. Can someone fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That particular answer apparently neither creates nor changes any symlinks, which suggests that you perhaps did something very different or unexpected. It certainly means that there's not enough information yet to offer helpful advice.

Comment: The same thing occurred to me today. I didn't even update the system. Just turned off ubuntu yesterday and when I turned on the pc today, it was exactly like yours. I didn't even have shortcuts on the desktop, but now all the directories in the home directory were copied to the desktop and are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did, and what caused this, remains unclear. You can restore the desktop as following:

- Delete the invalid symbolic links "Downloads", "Area de Trabalho" (which, I guess, corresponds to "Desktop" in an English setup), "Modelos" ("Templates") and "Publico" ("Public"). Try with the file manager first. If you cannot delete because the permissions are wrong, the delete using `sudo` in the terminal.
- Recreate the folders "Area de Trabalho", "Modelos" and "Publico".
- Open the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs" with a text editor.
- Correct the entries for the special folders so they point to the existing folder, e.g.

  ```
  XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Area de Trabalho"
  XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
  ...
  ```

Log out then log back in: you should again have normally functioning special folders, represented in the file manager with an emblem in the folder icon.

Comment: Thank you!! It helped a lot!